# Eclipse product export wizard produces an exe that requires administrator rights to run

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am creating an RCP app that i want to build using the eclipse product export wizard however every time i do the export it builds fine but the exe within the build requires admin rights to run.

I thought it was something to do with the configuration on the product so i added:

```
osgi.configuration.area
@user.home/Updater/configuration

osgi.instance.area
@user.home/Updater/workspace
```

This however dose not make any difference.

I am quite confused with this as i basically copied a product from the last app we made and it is basically identical but that export produced an exe that did not require admin.

Could it be a particular plugin i have in the dependencies that specifies admin?

Comment: Windows keeps track of .exe file origins, the one you copied must have come from a trusted source. It has nothing to do with plugins. You can fine-tune security/trusted places from Control Panel.

Comment: Yes i was thinking it could be a windows thing too however the other application i build uses the same exe which comes from the same location and it does not require admin to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the Launcher Name field in the Launching tab on the product.

If you put "updater" anywhere in the name of the launcher it will produce an exe that requires admin rights to run...

I am unsure why this happens maybe it is an eclipse thing when they compile the exe?

I just changed the name to something without Updater as the name and all went back to normal :D